# Can't get deleteItemAtIndexPath for collection View cells to work. swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Ok, I posted the question 3x and for some reason no ones solution so far has helped. I cannot get collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPath to work...

Everything seems to be connected fine. when i tap my deleteButton it doesnt actually delete the item.

**I have been at this for 3 days. PLEASE tell me what i missing :)**

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

protocol AddNewTrainerViewControllerDelegate: class {

    func addNewTrainerViewControllerDidCancel(controller: AddNewTrainerViewController)
    func addNewTrainerViewController(controller: AddNewTrainerViewController, didFinishAddingItem item: TrainerArray)
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
    func addNewTrainerViewController(controller: AddNewTrainerViewController, didFinishEditingItem trainer: TrainerArray)
    func addNewTrainerViewController(controller: AddNewTrainerViewController, didFinishDeletingItem item:TrainerArray)


}



class AddNewTrainerViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBAction func openPhotoLibrary(sender: AnyObject) {

        var photoPicker = UIImagePickerController()
        photoPicker.delegate = self
        photoPicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
        photoPicker.allowsEditing = true 
        self.presentViewController(photoPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var trainerPhoto: UIImageView!

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

        trainerPhoto.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let trainer = trainerToEdit {

            title = "Edit Trainer"
            textField.text = trainer.name
            trainerPhoto.image = trainer.trainerImage
            doneBarButton.enabled = true


            let deleteButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Trash, target: self, action: "deleteButton")
            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = deleteButton
        }
    }

    func deleteButton() {

        let item = TrainerArray()
        delegate?.addNewTrainerViewController(self, didFinishDeletingItem: item)


    }


    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    //outlet for done bar button item to control status
    @IBOutlet weak var doneBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        let oldText: NSString = textField.text!
        let newText: NSString = oldText.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
        if newText.length > 3 {
            doneBarButton.enabled = true
        } else {
            doneBarButton.enabled = false
        }

       return true
    }


    //Trainer Name Text Field
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    //action outlet for done button
    @IBAction func doneButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        if let trainer = trainerToEdit {

            trainer.name = textField.text!
            trainer.trainerImage = trainerPhoto.image!
            delegate?.addNewTrainerViewController(self, didFinishEditingItem: trainer)

        } else if trainerPhoto.image == nil {
            displayAlert("Please Add Your Trainer's Photo", message: "")

        } else if trainerPhoto.image != nil {

        let item = TrainerArray()
        item.name = textField.text!
        item.trainerImage = trainerPhoto.image!
        delegate?.addNewTrainerViewController(self, didFinishAddingItem: item)

        }

    }


    //action outlet for cancel or back button
    @IBAction func cancelButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        delegate?.addNewTrainerViewControllerDidCancel(self)
    }

    // doesn't allow selection of the row. Won't turn gray.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {

        return nil
    }

    weak var delegate: AddNewTrainerViewControllerDelegate?


    func displayAlert (title: String, message: String) {

        var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

    var trainerToEdit: TrainerArray?


    }
```

Here is the protocol method I am calling in the other view controller. keep in mind delegation works, because I am able to both add and edit items.. delete is the issue.

```
         func addNewTrainerViewController(controller: AddNewTrainerViewController, didFinishDeletingItem item: TrainerArray) {

        if let index = trainers.indexOf(item) {

            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)
            let indexPaths = [indexPath]
            if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath){

                configureTrainerForCell(cell, withTrainerArray: item)
                self.collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths)

            }
        }
            dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            saveTrainerItems()
    }
```

What am i missing? Thank you all.

Comment: You are sending a new, empty `TrainerArray` to your `didFinishDeletingItem` delegate method.  You need to send the item that you want to delete (i.e. `trainerToEdit`)

Comment: I am fairly new to swift(3 months). Teaching myself. Any Chance you can give me an exact example?

Comment: `delegate?.addNewTrainerViewController(self, didFinishDeletingItem: self.trainerToEdit`)` - presuming you have set `trainerToEdit` as the item that you want to delete before presenting this view controller

Comment: i changed my deleteButton to return        delegate?.addNewTrainerViewController(self, didFinishDeletingItem:self.trainerToEdit) and ran that application. when i clicked delete it crashed with a really long error, 1 sec ill post it.

Comment: erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: The error message tells you what you did wrong - You still have two objects in your array - you deleted the cell from the collectionView but not from the underlying data source, so there is an inconsistency.  You need to remove the item from your array that is driving your collection view

Comment: i am assuming this has something to do with the protocol method? maybe.... trainers.removeAtIndex ?

Comment: Sorry this is all so new to me.

Comment: @Paulw11 OMG! i got it! i added, self.trainers.removeAtIndex(index) and it worked!

Comment: @Paulw11 Three days of stress gone. Thank you! but before you go.. is there anything you recommend i do to get better with swift?